# How do I load huge amounts of JSON in PHP to essentially duplicate database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I'm writing an application in PHP that is going to do a lot of calculations using data from an API. I have it all working, except it is super slow becuase each request ends up going through 5 separate JSON files (often times wiht many fields that I never need.

A possible solution that I came up with was to simply create a file that processes everything and inserts it into a database so I can create more efficient queries to get only the values that I need.

I got this all set up, but since it was try to process a huge JSON file (http://api.vex.us.nallen.me/get_teams) it eventually timed out before anything was inserted.

Here is the file I created to process the teams.

```
<?php

$url = "http://api.vex.us.nallen.me/get_teams?nodata=true";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json);

$number_of_teams = $json_decoded->{'size'};
$teams_updated = 0;

echo $number_of_teams;

$hostname = "host";
$username = "user";
$password = "pw";
$database = "db";
$dbConnection = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

if($dbConnection->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

while($teams_updated < $number_of_teams) {

    $url = "http://api.vex.us.nallen.me/get_teams?limit_start=".$teams_updated."&limit_number=1000";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_decoded = json_decode($json);

    for( $i = 0; $i < count($json_decoded->{'result'}); $i++) {

        $team = $json_decoded->{'result'}[$i];
        $number = $team->{'number'};
        $program = $team->{'program'};
        $team_name = $team->{'team_name'};
        $robot_name = $team->{'robot_name'};
        $organisation = $team->{'organisation'};
        $city = $team->{'city'};
        $country = $team->{'country'};
        $grade = $team->{'grade'};

        if ($stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO teams (number, program, team_name, robot_name, organisation, city, country, grade) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number=?, program=? team_name=?, robot_name=?, organisation=?, city=?, country=?, grade=?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $number, $program, $team_name, $robot_name, $organisation, $city, $country, $grade);
            $stmt->execute();
            $teams_updated++;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Is there any more efficient JSON parser or different method I should be using to process all of this data?

Comment: Have you considered doing a bulk SQL insert?

Comment: You've included mysql in your tags, so I assume Mike Brant's suggestion makes the most sense for you, but I'd like to point out that this is exactly the type of problem that document DBs (like mongodb) were invented to solve.

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou Unfortunately I only have access to a MySQL database. I will look into Bulk Inserts though. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use SQLite, which could well be faster in some situations than MySQL, and should be less of an administrative hassle for you to maintain. It all depends on your use case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make it in 2 steps :

1. Do a script (PHP or other, it doesn't matter) that will process your JSON files and transform them in the format used by the SQL instruction `LOAD DATA INFILE` (that is csv-ish).
2. Do the actual insertion using raw SQL queries from command line, you don't need a script for that (bonus: no timeout).

Comment: Will this still work with the 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' clause? I plan on updating the database every week and I would like to update rather than add duplicate entries.

Comment: You can. The statement works mainly like an insert statement, with quite the same options. Look at the exact syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)